# How much heat do hurricanes transport from equatorial to more polar latitudes, and from ocean to atmosphere?

Tags: atmosphere

And how much does this heat compare with the total fraction of heat otherwise transported from equatorial to polar latitudes, and from ocean to atmosphere?